# Links html pages in different directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If i am having main folder, inside the main folder there are two sub-folder and in each sub-folder there is a page, example(in 1st sub-folder there is one.html and in 2nd there is two.html) and in main-folder i have index.html which has navigation menu bar, now how can i link them in menu bar without using absolute path. Help me if there is any script in javascript or jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

**From main folder:**

`<a href="/sub-folder1/one.html"> My Page </a>`

**From sub-folder to another sub-folder:**

`<a href="../sub-folder2/two.html"> My Page </a>`

**In JavaScript sub-folder to another sub-folder dynamically:**

HTML:

`<a id="link"> My Page </a>`

JavaScript:

```
var a = document.getElementById('link');
var subfolder = ... ; // your subfolder
var page = ... ; // your page to go to
a.href = "../"+subfolder+"/"+page;
```

Comment: no, suppose if your answer takes me to the one.html inside a sub-folder then from that sub-folder how can i reach to two.html which is in another sub-folder. I hope you understand what i am asking.                                                                      Thank you,

Comment: So you are saying from a sub-folder, how to go back and into another sub folder? If so `href="../sub-folder2/two.html"` , `..` means go back.

Comment: But it wont work if i want to switch to index.html(in main folder) to any files inside sub-folders. So, I want  it completely dynamic in javascript.

Comment: The answer I gave goes: subfolder1 -> main folder -> subfolder2. I will update the answer an include doing it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is root relative paths: http://ifyoucodeittheywill.com/2009/03/absolute-relative-and-root-relative-urls/

These always take the form of:

```
/Level1/Level2/file.html
```

Being root relative it always references the root point of the website. This is also very handy for your javascript and css resources, in that the link to them is always the same regardless of the folder depth or site architecture. E.g.

```
/Script/myScript.js 
/Style/site.css
```

Will work regardless of where file calling the resources is located in the website.